# Enable autocomplete for parsed arguments in getopts

Tags: bash, autocomplete, getopts

I have a bash script that uses `getopts` to parse command line arguments. One of the arguments, `-l <name>` is directed to an `if` statement that determines certain settings. Is it possible to have autocomplete work in the command line for entering the `<name>` parameter?

Here is the command line parsing part (`getopts`) of my script:

```
while getopts 'l:r:m:?h' c
do
  case $c in
    l) 
        library=$OPTARG 
        ;;
    r)  
        rename_config=$OPTARG 
        ;;
    m)  
        align_mm=$OPTARG
        ;;  
    h|?) usage 
        ;;
  esac
done
```

The library option (`-l`) refers to this part of the script:

```
if [ $library = "bassik" ];
    then
        read_mod="clip"
        clip_seq="GTTTAAGAGCTAAGCTGGAAACAGCATAGCAA"
        echo "Bassik library selected"
elif [ $library = "moffat_tko1" ];
    then
        read_mod="trim"
        sg_length=20    
        echo "Moffat TKO1 library selected"
elif [ $library = "sabatini" ];
    then
        read_mod="trim"
        sg_length=20    
        echo "Sabatini library selected"
fi
```

The part where the auto-completion should work are for "bassik", "moffat_tko1", and "sabatini" parameters.
So far, I have tried just hitting `<TAB>` right after `./script.sh -l`, but that does not work. I have googled it, but could not find anything that fits my situation (not sure also how to call this, new to bash).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That's basically what an autocomplete script does.

Comment: It is possible, but you have to give a few more specifics – what do you call your script like, what are the autocompletion options (is it a list of words, or somehow dynamically generated?) Have you tried something that didn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have edited my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I copied your script snippet in a file called *auto.sh* and set the execution permission on it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while getopts 'l:r:m:?h' c
do
  case $c in
    l) 
        library=$OPTARG 
        ;;
    r)  
        rename_config=$OPTARG 
        ;;
    m)  
        align_mm=$OPTARG
        ;;  
    h|?) usage 
        ;;
  esac
done


if [ $library = "bassik" ];
    then
        read_mod="clip"
        clip_seq="GTTTAAGAGCTAAGCTGGAAACAGCATAGCAA"
        echo "Bassik library selected"
elif [ $library = "moffat_tko1" ];
    then
        read_mod="trim"
        sg_length=20    
        echo "Moffat TKO1 library selected"
elif [ $library = "sabatini" ];
    then
        read_mod="trim"
        sg_length=20    
        echo "Sabatini library selected"
fi
```

Then, to set up an auto-completion for the `-l` option, you can begin with those basics steps (this can be future enhanced):

**1.** Create a completion script (e.g. ./auto-complete.sh) which contains the *libs* function to be called upon completion request (`-F` parameter of *complete* command). The function triggers the display of the library names (content of *COMPREPLY* array variable) if `-l` option is the word preceding the completion place (`$3` argument):

```sh
function libs()
{
  # $1 is the name of the command 
  # $2 is the word being completed
  # $3 is the word preceding the word being completed

  case $3 in
    -l) COMPREPLY+=("bassi")
        COMPREPLY+=("moffat_tko1")
        COMPREPLY+=("sabatini");;
  esac
}

complete -F libs auto.sh
```

**2.** Source the script in your local shell:

```
$ source ./auto-complete.sh
```

**3.** Launch the shell script and type `TAB` key twice after a space behind the `-l` option:

```
$ ./auto.sh -l <tab><tab>
bassik       moffat_tko1  sabatini
$ ./auto.sh  -l bassik
Bassik library selected
```

**4.** The preceding systematically lists all the choices when you type `TAB` key. To have a more accurate completion when typing the first letters, the completion script can be enhanced to use *compgen* command:

```sh
function libs()
{
  # $1 is the name of the command 
  # $2 is the word being completed
  # $3 is the word preceding the word being completed

  case $3 in
    -l) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "bassik moffat_tko1 sabatini" "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"));;
  esac
}

complete -F libs auto.sh
```

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! Thank you for you for putting so much effort in your answer.